# How to fetch the table in Rational Functional Tester for Desktop Based Application?

Tags: rft

I am using ITestDataTable getData = (ITestDataTable) element[0].getTestData("contents");.. But I am getting null value. but if i use the same code for web based application. I am able to fetch the table. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You havenot mentioned the control that you are interacting with  and which domain(.Net/Java etc).
Different controls support different types of data. If

```
getTestData("contents");
```

gives null , then try to use the  Insert Verification Point  wizard to capture Data VP on that control and see what are the available options  for the data VP for it.  If the VP wizard is not able to capture the data VP  for that control then getTestData("type") will also not work.